# What is the sequence a compiler processes information (strings, manipulators etc.) when encountered with an extraction or insertion operator?

Tags: c++

I am unsure as to why this line works. How does a compiler work to make this line of code perfectly legal. Does the cout process information from left to right, neglecting the information till the next extraction operator?

How does a compiler identify how to sequence the multiple existing strings?

```
std:: cout << "Hello world" << " this is a new line" << endl;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate about your doubts please? Other than suggesting, there isn't a new line in your example. The syntax is as calling the `operator<<()` function multiple times BTW.

Comment: What does "neglecting information" mean?

Comment: It is basically `f(g(h(std::cout, "Hello World"), " this is a new line"), std::endl)`, with `f`/`g`/`h` `operator <<` which does output and returns `std::cout`.

Comment: I was trying to understand as to if there is a special way compiler 'sees' cascaded operators (<<). The strings do not matter. They are placeholders. I wanted to understand precedence in this case. Why is 'Hello world' displayed first, why not 'this is a new line'. How does a compiler identify what information must be printed on the display first.
By neglecting information, i meant that as 'Hello world is being printed', does the compiler neglect 'this is a new line'? Or are the strings concatenated first and then printed altogether? I hope i was able to clarify my concerns.

Comment: @AbdulMoeez08 "_I wanted to understand precedence in this case._" The operator precedence (with accompanying associativity) is clearly defined [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<<` is really just `operator<<`. That overload for `std::ostream` returns itself to allow chaining of multiple `operator<<` calls so really it's just:

```
foo.print("Hello world").print(" this is a new line").print("\n");
```

Comment: Even though accepted, this doesn't actually answer the question as asked.

Comment: @Peter If it doesn't answer the OP's question why would OP accept it my friend? I took a stab at guessing what op was actually asking and it seems I was right.

Comment: OP's accept wrong answers all the time because they don't know better.

Answer (score 3):

This works based on two mechanics:

1. When `cout` (or `cin` or another stream from the `<iostream>` library) has the `<<` or `>>` operator called, it returns itself after doing the input or output. Therefore, `cout << "Hello world"` works just like `cout` for the rest of the line.
2. The `operator<<` call is [left-to-right associative](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence); that is, your line is equivalent to `((std::cout << "Hello world") << " this is a new line") << endl;`. Combined with point 1, this means that it works like running `cout << "Hello world";`, followed by `cout << " this is a new line";` and `cout << endl;`.

As a side note, in most cases you don't actually need `endl`. You should just include a newline in the string itself, as `" this is a new line\n"`. The only time you need to use `endl` is if you actually need the line to appear on the screen *right away*, which you usually don't. Because `endl` forces the line to appear immediately (it *flushes* the buffer), it takes a lot longer than just using a newline character.

Comment: The first point solved it for me. Also, thank you for the side note.